# Plotting several polar charts using matplotlib for a SOM

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates, self-organizing-maps

I have a self organizing map which has been plotted in several ways (using u-matrix and component planes charts) but I don't know what to do in order to plot a chart like this (composed by several polar charts):

[image]

I have a n-dimensional array which represents the trained SOM's neurons which is (56,56,6) where 6 is the input dimension, so each polar chart must have 6 "bars" representing the different attributes.

Comment: PS: I would like to know both the cases of the rectangular neurons and the hexagonal ones (as shown in the picture)

Comment: This is a typical problem you need to solve step by step. Can you draw a single of the desired plots? Only if yes, proceed. Can you then plot two of those in the same figure (and determine their positions) Only if so, proceed. Do you know the positions of cells in a hexagonal grid? Only if so, use them for positioning the plots. While I strongly doubt anyone will write this code for you, you may get help with each individual step when asking a well phrased question about it and showing the attempts that led to the problem.